# Is it dangerous to mix ActiveSupport::Concern modules with vanilla modules?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport, activesupport-concern

I know there's a dependency management system hidden behind `ActiveSupport::Concern`. I do not understand it completely (and I'm not sure I am ready to yet), but in a nutshell : is it possible to mix `ActiveSupport::Concern` with vanilla (non `ActiveSupport::Concern`) modules, or are there pitfalls ?

Here are some examples of the different usages I can think of

```
module Vanilla
  module ModuleIncludedInASC
    # Vanilla module
  end

  module ModuleIncludedInClass
    # Vanilla module
  end

module ASC
  module ConcernIncludedInClass
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    ...
  end

  module ConcernIncludedInASC
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    ...
  end

  module ConcernIncludingVanillaModulesIncludedInClass
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include Vanilla::VanillaConcernIncludedInASC
  end
  module ConcernIncludingASCConcernIncludedInASC
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include ConcernIncludedInASC
  end
end

class MyFoo
  include Vanilla::ModuleIncludedInClass
  include ASC::ConcernIncludedInClass
  include ASC::ConcernIncludingVanillaModulesIncludedInClass
end

# Ans also possibly, ActiveSupport::Concern modules included in vanilla modules...?
```

Could that potentially lead to problems ?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a problem.

I can't speak to the deep technical details, but I've never seen anyone mention it's risky, and I do this all the time. I have some models with 10+ `includes`. Some of those modules are using `ActiveSupport::Concern`, some aren't. Never encountered any issue.

I'd suggest trying it and post a new question if it does cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any problem yet, but yes, theoretically there is a potential problem.

The methods that are defined in a normal module are *appended* to the method lookup chain if you *include* that module in a class. So the methods defined in the class will override the methods in the normal module.

The methods that are defined in a concern's `included` block will be added *directly* to the class that includes the concern.

The result is, even if you include concern earlier than a normal module, the methods in a concern will always override the methods in a normal module.

#### Example

```
module Normal
  def foo
    'normal'
  end
end

module Concern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def foo
      'concern'
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Concern  # include concern first
  include Normal   # then include normal
end

Bar.new.foo  #=> "concern"
```

Maybe you would expect `"normal"` to be returned, but that's never gonna happen.

Comment: Thanks for this example ! It actually might happen to me in practice : when I write "abstract" modules, I sometimes define the interface explicitely with `def foo; raise NotImplementedError` and I am expecting other modules to override it with the implmeentation. if those other modules are not concerns then I may end up not overriding at all.